# Enabling elements in a table when checkmark from that row is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table. Imagine something like this (I will use pseudocode):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Checkbox</td>
  <td>Select</td>
  <td>Select</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Checkbox</td>
  <td>Select</td>
  <td>Select</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The thing is the selects are all disabled. When I check the checkbox it is supposed to enable all selects  OF THAT ROW. Before, I had this code in divs and it was possible to use siblings to find the selects. Here is the code I used:

```
    $('[name*=chkd]').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).siblings('select').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else{
            $(this).siblings('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

But now, since they are all inside  tags, I can't use that code. Can anyone shed some light as to what I can do to change this code so that it works with the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable Disable Controls in a table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745903/enable-disable-controls-in-a-table-row)

Answer (score 0):

They are not siblings anymore. So, you have to traverse from a common parent for each one.

```
$('[name*=chkd]').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('select').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else{
            $(this).closest('tr').find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your markup would look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select disabled>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select disabled>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select disabled>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select disabled>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code would give you the expected result:

```
$(function() {
    // When a checkbox is clicked.
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
        // Is it checked?
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

        // Look for the selects in the row and toggle their disabled property.
        $(this).closest("tr").find("select").prop("disabled", !checked);
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sf1dfwsm/2/)

References:

[.prop() | jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[.closest() | jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.find() | jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

The `input` is no longer a sibling of a `select`, so you need to find the parent's siblings, then find the `select`s in those elements.

```js
 $('[name*=chkd]').click(function() {
   var $siblings = $(this).parent().siblings().find('select');
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $siblings.removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
     $siblings.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkd" checked></td>
      <td><select><option>asdf</option></select></td>
      <td><select><option>asdf</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkd" checked></td>
      <td><select><option>asdf</option></select></td>
      <td><select><option>asdf</option></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for select elements with `find` and assign the disabled property to the checkbox value:

```
$('.myTable').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  var $controls = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').prop('disabled', this.checked);
  if (this.checked) {
    $controls.val(0)
  }
}).find(':checkbox').change();
```

You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DamianDMN/hzacwwbd/)