# How To Enable/Disable a Table Row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a pre made function in jQuery wherein when you click a button it will enable a row. Then if you click it again, it will disable the row. I found about toggle() and toggleClass(). But it does work when it calls a function. The thought is somewhat like this but I know the syntax is wrong.

**jQuery**

```
function disableRows(){
$("#test1table tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('input:text').prop('disabled', true);
});

function enableRows(){
$("#test1table tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('input:text').prop('disabled', false);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.yearButt').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass(enableRows(), disableRows());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) not toggleClass, toggle will call functions alternatively on each click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.yearButt').toggle(
      function() { enableRows(); }, 
      function() { disableRows(); }
    );
  });
});
```

You can also optimize your enable disable code by removing loops and using proper selectors for desired element

`$("#test1table").find("input,button,textarea,select").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013701/select-all-tr-elements-except-first-tr-in-a-table-with-css)

Comment: Actually this should be marked as the **correct** answer. Tested and works, without fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think below code help you to understand the requirements:

Ref: [Enable Disable Controls in a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745903/enable-disable-controls-in-a-table-row)

```js
$(document).on('change', '.chkView', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.chkEdit, .chkDelete').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_forms">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkView"/>View</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkEdit" disabled/>Edit</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkDelete" disabled/>Delete</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkView"/>View</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkEdit" disabled/>Edit</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkDelete" disabled/>Delete</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yearButt').click(function(){
        var enabled = parseInt($(this).data('enabled'));
        $("#test1table tbody tr input:text").prop('disabled', enabled );

        $(this).data('enabled', !enabled)
    });
});
```

Comment: When I clicked the button, it enables the rows but when I clicked it again. it won't disable the rows back

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you're looking for `.toggle()`, not `.toggleClass()` :)

Then...

This isn't doing what you expect:

```
$(this).toggle(enableRows(), disableRows());
```

This is invoking the two functions *immediately* and then toggling based on the *results* of those functions.  (Which are both `undefined`.)  Instead of *executing* the functions, you just want to *reference* the functions so that `.toggle()` will execute them according to its logic:

```
$(this).toggle(enableRows, disableRows);
```

Note: If your code snippet is complete, then you also forgot the closing `}` after each of those functions.  Simple typo.

Comment: Looks like `$(this).toggleClass(enableRows, disableRows);` doesn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: @dfsq: Oh, good catch.  I didn't even notice that.  I might need to look up proper usage for toggling, it's been a while.  **Edit:** Fixed, thanks!

Comment: I tried doing this but what happens is that when I click the button, it disappears and it didn't enable the rows

Comment: @KaelJasper: Can you replicate the behavior in a jsFiddle using just the relevant HTML and just the code in the question (or an answer)?